# Cloud Build to pick up new GitHub Repositories

Tags: github, google-cloud-build

I want to use Cloud Build in the following way:

1. A user creates a new repo in my GitHub organization.
2. Cloud Build picks up that the new repository was created, and starts a pipeline.
3. The Cloud Build pipeline started in the previous step creates more Cloud Build pipelines (probably through the CLI or through Terraform). All of these Cloud Build pipelines will programmatically connected to the newly created GitHub repo, as mentioned in [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/github/connect-repo-github?generation=2nd-gen).

Is this possible? How can I get Cloud Build to pick up newly created GitHub repositories in my organization? If its not possible to use Cloud Build for that, are there other tools that I should use instead?

Comment: Have you tried performing the steps listed in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/github/connect-repo-github?generation=2nd-gen#connecting_a_github_host_programmatically)? If so what are the errors you encountered?